# CHS Record reading cylinder

Tags: c

So according to this wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record CHS record is 3 bytes but sector shares bits with cylinder.

Question is: In order to get cylinder value i would shift last 2 bits left by 8
for example:

```
uint16_t cylinder = chs_cylinder_byte | ((chs_sector_byte & 0xC0) << 8);
```

The reason behind question: why it was not done so cylinder and sector is a single 16 bit value where high 10 bits are cylinder and low 6 are sector value, so the whole read oepration can be done with single mask to get value. instead of shifting and masking.

Comment: Could you be more specific on what your question is, there doesn't really seem to be one. That being said, this does seem to be how you would do it.

Comment: Yes, that looks right where `chs_sector_byte` is the 2nd byte and `chs_cylinder_bytes` is the 3rd byte in the record (for the CHS address of first absolute sector in partition). Are you not getting expected results?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yes i do get the right results, but i am more concerned why it was designed this way, because we could simply use masking operation instead of masking and shifting.

Comment: @ThomasJager i updated my question.

Comment: Up top it explains `"(all multi-byte fields are little-endian) "`, so in it describing what each bit is in the 2nd and 3rd byte, that should eliminate confusion. As to "Why?" it was done that way originally, when drives were measured in Kilobytes instead of Terabytes every bit was important, so they were encoding every bit to make that information as small as possible. Remember dual-drive 8-inch floppies?

Comment: @David i am not confused with endianes that was in question yesterday, more concerned with additional shifting operation to be performed. since i can read 16 byte partition record in 4 4 byte aligned reads and quickly and with less code get all values.

Comment: Oh, you are free to read the bits any way you like. You could set up a struct with bitfilelds as well. Just confirm your reading the information you think you are. Your approach with `C0` just pick of bits 6-7 from the first byte and then the left-shift by 8 and or'ing with the next byte just includes them in the proper place. If reading 4-byte aligned works for you -- that's fine.